# Format X axis interval in the Chart - Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have the following code which display the line on the chart. I could not able to find how to format the x axis. I would like to show every thousand interval similar to y axis (0,1000,2000,3000,4000, etc). I am using Kendo UI.

```
           function createChart() {
                    $("#chart").kendoChart({
                        title: {
                            text: "Units sold"
                        },
                        dataSource: {
                            data: stats
                        },                        
                        categoryAxis: {                            
                            labels: {                                
                                step: 1000,
                                format: "n0"
                            },
                        },
                        series: [{
                            type: "area",
                             line: {
                                style: "smooth"
                            },
                            field: "x",
                            categoryField: "y"
                        }], 
                    });
                }
```

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nDS3S/37/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get right, your code doesn't works because the `step` doesn't really mean that would be shown a label for each *1000*, but in fact it will show a label for each *serie*. So your chart doesn't have 1000 series, that is why only `0` was displayed.

If you change your step to `5`, you will see the labels, but displaying the exactly number for that specific serie.

[Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/nDS3S/38/).

I'm afraid you can't achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why I could keep it 5, why not a hundred or a thousand? How could I make an interval of a thousand?

Comment: @ilyasUyanik you see those vertical lines? Those are the steps. So its showing a label in each 5 steps. A step is generated no matter what value it represents. So it can't be distributed equally for each 1000 numbers. At least that is what I understood. I advice you to post it in a Kendo forum, maybe a specialist or a support user can give you a better answer.

Comment: @ilyasUyanik sorry, nope.